# Unable to change access permissions on external ntfs Harddrive

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, chmod, ntfs

I am fairly new with Linux when it comes to mounting hard drives, so hopefully this is a simple question. I recently purchased a 3TB hard drive that would have read/write access with both Mac and Linux. The first step I took was to format the hard drive partition on a Mac system with "Windows NT Filesystem (Tuxera NTFS)".

Then I connected the hard drive to the Linux machine and ran the command:

```
sudo mount -o umask=0,uid=name,gid=name /dev/sdb2 /mnt/point/
```

So currently I have read/write access on both Linux and Mac. The slight problem I have now is that each directory that is created on the hard drive on the Linux machine has all the permissions enabled. For example when creating a new directory called "test" and then running "ls -lh" the output shows:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 name name 0 Nov 13 13:18 test
```

and the directory "test" is highlighted in green on the terminal. I tried modifying the access permissions by executing:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /mnt/point/
```

but this does not change anything, and the "test" directory is still highlighted. Would anybody happen to know if there are some restrictions with permission changes on NTFS hard drives? If so, is there possible way to solve this problem?

If worst comes to worst, and there is no solution. What is the best partition that would be able to have read/write access with Mac and Linux?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  ntfs has no knowledge of Linux permissions and ownerships. The only weapons at your disposal are mount options.